# Linux kernel source git checkout to specific version

Tags: linux, git, linux-kernel, git-checkout

When I am in Linux kernel git local repo and want to `git checkout` to some specific version of sources I see e.g. the following options:

```
git checkout v4.4
v4.4       v4.4-rc1   v4.4-rc2   v4.4-rc3   v4.4-rc4   v4.4-rc5   v4.4-rc6   v4.4-rc7   v4.4-rc8
```

But there are much more versions in https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.4.233/source.
E.g. I want to checkout to *v4.4.233*.
How can I do this in my local repo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The minor (stable) releases are in the `stable` repository:
https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/